# Avoid passing pytest arguments as command line arguments

Tags: python, pytest

A simple question really. When I run:

```
pytest test_file.py
```

my python app returns an error as `test_file.py` is not recognised as valid argument.

How can I avoid this to happen ? In other words, how can prevent my app to accept `pytest` arguments as its own ?

Thank you for your hints !

Roland

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing your whole app into your test code? You should move the logic out to its own module, and only import that into your test code. For example:

File main.py

```
import sys
from my_logic import do_stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    expected_cmd_arg = sys.argv[1]
    do_stuff(expected_cmd_arg)
```

File my_logic.py:

```
def do_stuff(expected_cmd_arg):
    pass
```

File test_my_logic.py:

```
import pytest
from my_logic import do_stuff

def test_my_logic():
     do_stuff("hello")
```

That way you never import a file which reads `sys.argv` into your tests.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer ! Thing is, I use `argparse` in some module to define some package-wide variables either set from command line or from input files. Say, if I haven't got command line args, search in the defaults. Then, I can use these variables from everywhere. Side note, not sure it is the best design. But what I realised is that somehow when calling modules in `pytest` (that depend upon the default variables) it is  considering `pytest` args as the app owns and therefore running into errors.

Comment: pytest does not "call" your app, pytest is its own app which just uses parts of your code. If your code reads sys.argv when being run from pytest, it will of course take the args pytest was started with. That is why you should only ever access sys.argv in the main file (which you don't import with pytest) in fact that's all your main file should do really. One of the bonus points of writing tests is that it highlights problems in your design like this. I would place those app-wide variables in a settings object, which you set variables on at launch, either from argv, or in a test setup method.

Comment: OK great, I see thanks for the tip really. It'll be useful :)